# How can jQuery wrap form input and next text by LABEL tag?

Tags: jquery, word-wrap

i have this:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" />
AAA
<p>BBB</p>
<div>CCC</div>
...
```

and want to wrap the input and next text by LABEL tag like this:

```
...
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    AAA
</label>
<p>BBB</p>
<div>CCC</div>
...
```

how i can do this by jQuery?

Comment: You can do this with the help of text() method in jQuery i guess

Comment: do you have a parent `<div>` wrapping around this HTML ??

Comment: @Murali no. text() method return inner text of an element. so text() method is usefull if i want to get text of 2nd code label inner text :)

Comment: @bipen it is unknown! i want to write a code that convert all input to labeled by its next text node!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.parent').contents().filter(function(){
     return this.localName === 'input' || this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrapAll('<label></label>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cja4H/

Or:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
   $(this).add(this.nextSibling).wrapAll('<label/>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BkpgX/

Comment: it can be improved by using `$("input[type=checkbox]").parent()` instead of `$('.parent')` selector :)